# How to avoid starting a new paragraph at a new page?

Tags: paragraphs, page

I am using LaTeX to write a thesis now and there exists a problem that every time a new paragraph can not be fully situated on the current page, the system will put it completely on a new page, leaving large blanks at the current page. Is there any way to let the system break the paragraph and put it separately on two pages?

I have pasted my code below.

```
\documentclass[cit,thesis,plain,nochapterblankpages,uglyheadings]{puthesis-cot}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,setspace,caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{spaced}{\\[2ex]}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator*{null}{ }
\captionsetup[table]
{format=plain,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false,labelsep=null,skip=0pt}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=null,justification=centering,singlelinecheck=false,font=doublespacing}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\newcommand{\ip}{\mbox{}\indent}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{italicdesc}{description}{4}
\setlist[italicdesc]{font=\normalfont\itshape}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\raggedright
\parindent=0.5in
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind}
\hyphenpenalty=5000 
\tolerance=1000
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace, caption}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={stretch=0.5}}
\captionsetup[table]{font={stretch=0.5}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}
    {-\baselineskip}{0.2\baselineskip}{\bf\leftline}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{1}{0mm}
    {-\baselineskip}{0.2\baselineskip}{\bf\leftline}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}

\newcommand{\margins}{\Repeat{Show where the margins for the page are.}{4}}

\let\en=\ensuremath

\newcommand{\ve}[2]{\en{#1_1},~\en{#1_2},\ \ldots,~\en{#1_{#2}}}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}
{\Baselinestretch{1}\setlength{\itemsep}{12pt plus 0.1pt}\settowidth}
{}{}
\apptocmd{\thebibliography}
{\normalsize}
{}{}
\interlinepenalty=10000
\begin{document}
```

Comment: normally LaTeX does break paragraphs, so you are doing something to prevent this. You will have to show some code.

Comment: By setting `\interlinepenalty` to 10000 you're essentially saying do not break paragraphs across pages. Why do you have that in your preamble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The settings you have

```
\hyphenpenalty=5000
\tolerance=1000
```

will make bad paragraphs, with large spaces between words in order to avoid hyphenation.

But the real problem is

```
\interlinepenalty=10000
```

which ***prohibits*** TeX from splitting any paragraph across pages, because a penalty of 10000 is essentially infinite. So there is no feasible page break point between lines of a paragraph. The only points where a page break is possible is therefore *between* paragraphs.

Remove all three settings.

---

I'd also remove

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}
    {-\baselineskip}{0.2\baselineskip}{\bf\leftline}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{1}{0mm}
    {-\baselineskip}{0.2\baselineskip}{\bf\leftline}}
\makeatother
```

or, at least, change `\bf\leftline` into `\bfseries`. The command `\bf` has been obsolete for 25 years and `\leftline` simply prevents line breaks in a section title; if it's longer than the text width, it will go beyond the right margin *without* any warning.

There are several other things that make the preamble to look like it comes down from a few generations of students, each one adding their own bits.

Start with a fresh preamble and add only what you *really* need.